# Python connect Azure SQL with pyodb on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, odbc, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a Azure SQL server with python on a MacOS (while I can on Microsoft).

And always get the same error:

***pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")***

My Config files are:

```
[MYMSSQL]
    host = azureserver.database.windows.net
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.3
    database = SQLPRIDB
```

etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

etc/odbc.ini:

```
[MYMSSQL]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Servername          = MYMSSQL
```

When I try to connect with tsql:

```
 tsql -S MYMSSQL -U myuser -P mypassword
```

I get the following error:

***"Cannot open server "MYMSSQL" requested by the login.  The login failed."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed***

*** I do connect when using the -H (Host), -p (Port) and -D (Database) with tsql*** See below:

```
 tsql -H azureserver.database.windows.net -p 1433 -D SQLPRIDB -U myuser -P mypassword
```

Has anyone experienced the same? Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python connect Azure SQL with pyodb on MacOS - AD Authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881752/python-connect-azure-sql-with-pyodb-on-macos-ad-authentification)

Comment: Have you created a rule that allows your IP address to connect for the SQL server in a portal?